# sync files from ftp to local system using microsoft sync frame work

Tags: .net, ftp, microsoft-sync-framework

I would like to synchronize a file directory with an FTP directory using Microsoft Sync Framework.

is there any resource available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sync Framework file sync providers doesn't support synchronizing over ftp or http. you will have to build a custom provider that works against the ftp side.

Comment: do you think this is the only way to solve it. can you provide some example for custom checking.